# Integrating Google Sign-In into your web app is not working

Tags: google-api, localhost, google-oauth, virtualhost, google-signin

I am trying to implement Google Sign-In. i am following this link https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in .

I have created a virtual host in my local system http://opencart.loc and i am trying to implement Google Sign-In with http://opencart.loc.

When i am configuring project on final page i am getting error.

```
 Something went wrong. Please try again.
```

This not working with any local virtual host but it working with http://localhost

You can see in bellow screen what i am doing wrong or google sign in is not working with virtual host.

Step 1 :

[image]

Step 2 :

[image]

Step 3 :

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can add http://localhost to make webpage just to your computer.

Comment: Add that where?